# Is there a correct way in Doctrine to nest 'OR' where clauses?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a query that pulls in some jobs if they have an end date and are not completed which produces the desired result:

**real code**

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('j')
                ->where('j.completed = :false OR j.completed is NULL')
                ->andWhere('j.has_due_date = :true')
                ->andWhere('j.has_due_date = :true')
                ->setParameters( array(
                    'false' => FALSE,
                    'true' => TRUE
                ) )
                ->orderBy('j.due_date', 'asc')
                ->getQuery();
```

**result**

```
SELECT j FROM App\Entity\Jobs j 
    WHERE (
        j.completed = :false 
        OR j.completed is NULL
    ) 
    AND j.has_due_date = :true 
    ORDER BY j.due_date ASC
```

I'm wanting to follow the DQL best practice for this and feel like there is another way or writing this and only having a single `WHERE` clause per call on a `->where` variant (`andWhere()`, `orWhere()`)

In my mind it's something like this but I can't find anything out there to confirm it:

**pseudo code**

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('j')
                  ->where( $requiredClass->
                                ->where('j.completed = :false')
                                ->orWhere('j.completed is NULL')
                                ->setParameter('false', FALSE) 
                  )
                  ->andWhere('j.has_due_date = :true')
                  ->setParameter('true', TRUE) 
                  ->orderBy('j.due_date', 'asc')
                  ->getQuery();
```

Main questions are:

- Is there a way to do this the second way?
- am I overcomplicating things unnecessarily?
- if there is a second way to do this as mentioned, the first statement works so why should it matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the official documentation for `QueryBuilder` best practice - the right way is to use the helper method `QueryBuilder::expr()` and also the `Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr` helper class. [High level API methods](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/query-builder.html#high-level-api-methods)

i.e.:

```
// create QueryBuilder
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('j');

// build conditions
$qb->where(
    $qb->expr()->orX(
        $qb->expr()->eq('j.completed', ':false'),
        $qb->expr()->isNull('j.completed')
    )
)
->andWhere(
    $qb->expr()->eq('j.has_due_date', ':true')
)
->andWhere(
    $qb->expr()->eq('j.has_due_date', ':true')
)
->setParameters(array(
    'false' => FALSE,
    'true' => TRUE
))
->orderBy('j.due_date', 'asc');

// get query
$query = $qb->getQuery();

// execute and get result
$result = $query->getResult();
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for this. +1 for formatting and readability :)

Comment: quick one - Does it not need to be `$query = $qb->where(..` to be able ot call the `->execute()` method further down or it it callable just from  `$qb`? e.g. `$qb->execute();`

Comment: QueryBuilder is just builder and not execute query. You must first get query object (instance of `Doctrine\ORM\Query`) from builder `$query = $qb->getQuery()` and them execute by `$query->execute()`.

Comment: Yeah. I think we are on the same page for this. The above should be `$query = $qb->where(..` as it ends with `->getQuery();`. Othewise the `getQuery()` is obsolete there, right? I've made an edit to show you what I mean.

Comment: You have right! I edited my answer to show, how to get result by using QueryBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

Using the query builder should be easier and more understandable

```
    public function someFunction()
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('j');

        $orX = $qb->expr()->orX();
        $andX = $qb->expr()->andX();

        $orX->add($qb->expr()->eq('j.completed', $qb->expr()->literal(false)));
        $orX->add($qb->expr()->isNull('j.completed'));

        $andX->add($qb->expr()->eq('j.has_due_date', $qb->expr()->literal(true)));

        $qb->andWhere($orX, $andX)
            ->orderBy('j.due_date', 'asc')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }
```

Comment: I'm sure that is right but that is incredibly hard to read 0_0